# Stack Overflow Careers / About Page says there are "0 top Stack Overflow users"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The page at the URL below has an error referring to the number of Stack Overflow users.

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about

Says:

> Employers can also search through the public profiles of **0** top Stack Overflow users, and request to contact them.

Comment: That's bizarre; nice catch.

Comment: If you want to upload pictures, please don't use secure/private services, it's quite pointless since only you can see the picture and all others get a 404 error page. You have image upload right here in the editor, and free image hosting like imgur in the worst case, then others can embed the picture later.

Answer (score 5):

Nice catch. I'll go ahead and take a look, was lookin for something to do tonight anyways :)

*EDIT*: Ok, that sentence referenced what we called "mini-profiles", which were essentially the public information available in StackOverflow profiles (pretty much exactly what the sentence says). That whole mini-profile system has been deprecated, so that sentence is no longer applicable. I removed it for now. The change will go live on the next build out (probably some time tomorrow).

Comment: Doesn't Careers site use the API for those things?

Comment: Yes, but the job that was querying those numbers was turned off a little while ago. That sentence was probably just overlooked.

Comment: What is that "mini profile"? Never heard of it, so bit curious what it was. :)